# Simulated robots in Gazebo/Hydro

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, ros-hydro, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

in Hydro, are there some working robot simulations? I mean Gazebo models etc. I know only about Turtlebot but I would rather do some experiments with an omnidirectional platform. Unfortunately, PR2 simulator stack is not available ([doesn't compile](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_simulator/issues/93)) as well as Care-O-Bot (not released but there is hydro branch on github - need to try it)...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133406/simulated-robots-in-gazebo/hydro/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-25**:
Thanks for tip. But I need simulated sensors like camera, 3D laser etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know any for Gazebo, but Stage Simulations are working in Hydro, if that is an option for you.

---

Originally posted by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) with karma: 336 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0